# c++ : Pthreads or Linux processes

Tags: c++, linux

Let us suppose I have **different data structures** in c++ on Linux

```
Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4 and many more
```

Afterwards, I make use of a network trace file (wireshark file). Send each packet to all these above data files. If anyone of them sets a flag for the packet. I want all the other data files to stop processing on that packet and move to the next packet in that network trace file.

In my scenario, which one will be better to use :

Pthreads or Linux processes (fork...)

Comment: Define "better to use". Or better yet, try both and profile according to your needs.

Comment: Do you have a memory restriction? Are you experienced with IPC, Shared Memory or Concurrency? All of these effect the answer i suppose.

Comment: Processes have much more overhead and are harder to control and to communicate with. The much better choice would be threads. The best choice is probably to use [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread)

Comment: @Faruxx If IPC is high then should I prefer threads?

Comment: Can't say. Still completely depend on your constraints: Security, Reliablity, Reusablity etc. But threads are much more easier to share data between. If you are not sure just go with threads, than if there is any case you have to switch to process such as standalone working or you may want to distribute each piece to different PCs, may be then.

Answer (score 2):

Processes have individual address spaces where each heave a separate heap, stack and code laying inside. Loading processes  require OS to create and manage memory resources.Data transferring through one to another require OS support, Inter Process Communication technologies such as Shared Memory or Pipes in case of Linux. Also each time accessing data that is protected by a shared semaphore, will require system calls. That will reduce your speed highly. Processes are protected from others by OS. If one process works right than the chance of another to break it is hard. Processes create a sandbox where you code is secured from others.

Thread's are more light weight. Creating and Deleting takes less time and afford. Doesn't have separate address space (page tables). Easy to share data one to another. Doesn't require OS support for that. But Threads are more vulnerable the mistakes of other threads. And still for the shared data you need concurrency tools such as semaphores or mutexes.

A small example of this is most browsers use threads to manage tab's. But when one fail mostly all application crash. But Chrome runs each tabs and extensions as different processes; If one crashes you still have others without major problem.

Go with threads if you are not sure. They will satisfy your needs stated in the question without problem.

Comment: Like I said earlier, If one process sets a flag for the packet then all other processes should move to next packet in network trace file. SOme sort of IPC is involved here. So, in this scenario should I prefer threads?

Comment: Okay. One more question, if I make us of processes in linux then instead of having each process  its own network trace file. I just have one copy of network trace file and each process reads packet from it. Will this approach work with linux processes?

Comment: All files in Linux are assumed to be shared (from the concept of everything is a file). If you only want to have one copy of network trace file in memory than one of the processes (or another process which just create shared memory and spawn new processes) should open a file with shared flag or create a shared memory and load file contents there. And still need to manage the concurrency then. Much much more complicated than a thread approach. Still your call though.